# What are 7 bit / 8 bit environments for control functions according to ISO/IEC 6429:1992?

Tags: terminal, escape-characters

I am learning ECMA-48 and I see a lot of notes about 7 bit and 8 bit environments for control functions. For example:

> NOTE LS0 is used in 8-bit environments only; in 7-bit environments
> SHIFT-IN (SI) is used instead.

Could anyone explain the difference between them and give real examples when each of them is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very early printers might have two colours on the ribbon, like mechanical typewriters did.  SI and SO switched between the optional colour and the normal colour.  Note that this is not the same usage as the shift key!

Early printers and terminals (I'll call them all just terminals from now on) used a 7-bit ASCII code.  Typically the eighth bit was used as parity, but this had to be configured.  To allow for additional characters some terminals had additional built-in character sets, or else the ability to download them.  To switch between them SI and SO were hijacked.  For instance to print in Katakana you would send SO, and later to go back to Latin-1 send SI.

As eight-bit systems became more common additional control codes became available.  Two of the additional codes were SSI and SSO where "SS" stands for single shift.  For instance to print a single graphical character you might use  rather than having to send <glyph which runs the risk of the screen turning into "hieroglyphs" as my users used to call them.  To distinguish between these modes, the original SI and SO were renamed LSI and LSO (ie Locking Shift) but retained their original behaviour.

So to summarise LSI=SI and LSO=SO, it's just the names that vary between the two environments.

As an example: suppose that I had the UK character set as my default.  I wish to quote a bit of French, let's say "garçon".  I would send down the line 67 61 72 0E 5C 0F 6F 6E.  Note the 0E and 0F surrounding the 5C, without that the glyph backslash would have been printed.

I've nabbed the details from the "LA75 Companion Printer: Programmer Reference Manual" published by digital, but any 1980s or 1990s printer or terminal manual should show broadly the same.  Details do vary between models and over time though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can't understand one thing - are 7 bit environments used today?

Comment: I am just totally confused but 7/8 bit environments. For example, from `man ascii` `ASCII  is the American Standard Code for Information Interchange.  It is a 7-bit code.`

Comment: The earliest code was of course Morse, and that sends one bit at a time.  In the 1870s (with modifications in 1901) a five-bit code was developed.  It had a shift function which allowed the code to switch between letters (uppercase only) and numbers+symbols.  The was the International Telegraph Alphabet No. 1 (ITA1).  It could be sent bit-by-bit, or else as five bits at once punched across a paper tape.  It was updated to ITA2 in 1924.  In 1963 ITA2 was used as the basis of a seven bit code: ASCII.  It embeds the earlier five bit codes within it.  ASCII uses just 7 bits.

Comment: Communication lines can be noisy, and so 7 bit-ASCII was usually transmitted with a parity bit that allows the receiver to detect errors and ask for a retransmission.  with improving transmission lines this eight bit was hijacked to double the number of symbols available.  This was formalised as ISO-8859-1.  To internationalise the situation Unicode was build upon ISO-8859.  So: If you read just the lowest 7 bits you are reading 7-bit ASCII.  If you read 8 bits it is 8-bit ISO-8859, any more bits are Unicode.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. Do I understand correctly - today both 7 bit and 8 bit systems are used, so, when I process text with control functions I first of all need to know if this is a 7 bit or 8 bit system?

Comment: 8-bit includes all of the 7-bit, so if you use 7-bit it will work in an 8-bit environment.  The reverse does not work: sending an 8-bit value (if the most significant bit is set) to a 7-bit system will confuse it.  However, the number of 7-bit devices is tiny.  A few old machine tools and plotters.  If you are using virtual terminals I can see no reason to restrict things to 7-bit except for educational purposes.